# TABLE wider than containing DIV

Tags: html, css

In the example below, also available [here](http://downloads.tersus.com/misc_files/wide_table.html),  both WebKit (Safari 5, Chrome 10.0.648.205) and Mozilla (FF 4) keep DIV div around the visible width of the browser window, while the TABLE is as wide as its content.

I would expect the DIV to grow as wide as the TABLE, but since the behavior is consistent across browsers, I suspect this is a feature rather than a bug.

Interestingly, if the DIV is set to have float:left, [it does grow as wide as the table](http://downloads.tersus.com/misc_files/wide_table_float.html).

Any explanations?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Wide Table</title>
<style>

#container {
    background-color:blue;
/*    float:left;*/
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <table >
       <tr id="tr">
         <td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td><td>Table&nbsp;Cell</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question answered my question! The float "growth" is what I was looking for. Setting display to inline-block also works, and is what I ultimately settled on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Block elements take the width of their parent by default, not the width of their content; height on the other hand, works the other way around: block elements take the height of their content by default rather than the height of their parent. Things work this way because HTML/CSS is built around the usual top-to-bottom layout of English text.

So, your `#container` takes the width of `<body>` and then the `<table>` inside `#container` overflows outside `#container`. If you put `overflow: hidden` on `#container` you'll clip the `<table>`, `overflow-x: auto;` on `#container` will add a scrollbar.

**UPDATE**: As far as floating elements are concerned, the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#lsquo) has this to say:

> The used value of ‘width’ is the computed value, unless that is ‘auto’, when used value is the shrink-to-fit width.

The default width will be auto so [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#shrink-to-fit) it is:

> Calculation of the **shrink-to-fit** width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks.

There are no possible line breaks in your `<table>` so the floated `#container` will take on the entire width of its `<table>` child.

Comment: And float, like inline block and table cell, uses a ["shrink-to-fit"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width) algorithm which looks at the content to calculate the width of the container

Comment: @Youval: Looks like you got to the standard before my update. I added some links to the CSS3 working draft for posterity.

Answer (score -3):

I generally set the size of the div, and let the table adjust itself to the div. Not sure if that bit of insight will help or not.